# Password Policies location

Tags: passwords

Trying to locate Password Policies section.  Does this section still exist and can I still set a password to "never expire"?

The tutorial I'm watching says that it should be in Administration Setup->Security Controls-> Password Policy

**Update:** New route is:

-> Setup (top right-hand of the page)

-> Administer (left navigation)

-> Security Controls

-> Password Policy

Comment: its Security Controls -> Password Policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be still there indeed. To make it easier, just start typing 'password' in the quick find/search box and it'll pop up.

[image]

Comment: Found it. I couldn't locate the Administrative Setup section because it was moved  and renamed to 'Setup' in the top right-hand side of the page .